# I am getting a localhost didn’t send any data error

Tags: php, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am a newbie with docker but I want to try it so I can use it with my existing laravel project.

Please note that the things I have here are just from different sources of learning from the internet.

For starters, I can have nginx and php-fpm up and running with this docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
    web:
        build: .
        volumes:
            - D:\code\project:/usr/share/nginx/html
        ports:
            - "80:80"

    php:
        image: php:7.1-fpm
        volumes:
            - D:\code\project:/usr/share/nginx/html
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:mainline-alpine
WORKDIR D:\code\project
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

./default.conf

```
server {
    # The port to listen on
    listen 80;
    # The root directory, which must exactly match the internal volume share
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    
    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # For all files with the PHP extension run the following
    location ~ ^/.+\.php(/|$) {
        # Pass the request to the host "php" and port 9000 (default PHP-FPM port).
        # The "php" host name is generated from the application name in the
        # Docker Compose file that was previously defined.
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        # Include the default NGINX FastCGI Parameters
        include fastcgi_params;
        # Define one additional parameter telling PHP-FPM where to find the file
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

The result in http://localhost/phpinfo.php:

[image]

The result in http://localhost

[image]

But as you can see, I need the PHP PDO extension/driver for laravel.

So, I am trying to install said PHP extension thru the Dockerfile and I am stucked with the issue "localhost didn’t send any data error"

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
    web:
        build: .
        volumes:
            - D:\code\project:/usr/share/nginx/html
        ports:
            - "80:80"

    php:
        build: .
        volumes:
            - D:\code\project:/usr/share/nginx/html
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:mainline-alpine
WORKDIR D:\code\project
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

FROM php:7.1-fpm
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

./default.conf - same as above, no changes

The result in http://localhost/phpinfo.php:

[image]

http://localhost:

[image]

The containers are up and running:

[image]

Am I missing something? I do not know how to debug with docker or where to view logs or errors.

I have been stucked with this for 3 days. Can someone please help?

Comment: _"Am I missing something?"_ Sorry if stating the obvious: Do not use the Dockerfile, don't run your own container image build, use the working, existing image. And then please complain and _tell_ why that is not an option and what your concrete question is regarding the build and provide a [mre] that is about the build and _test_ of the container. You can [edit] your question for all the clarifications.

Comment: And please explain the rationale behind the Dockerfile you have in the question, e.g. share your rationale for each line in it. My knowledge is limited and it is the first time I've seen the use of the directives in the form you have it. Does it even passes the build test?

Comment: @hakre I have edited my post. I hope the information I have given is sufficient.

Comment: Sorry for the bad news: Screenshots. They may go away, are hard to read, and add more noise than they provide info. Use relevant text instead, e.g. verbatim copies of error message, program commands and their output (e.g. shell), and for a HTTP url its suffficent to have the URL and you can state it can't be reached. Or use curl(1) on the command-line.  ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors))

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to solve it.

What I did was to split the Dockerfile into two, putting it inside separate sub-folders, one for nginx and one for php.

./nginx/Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:mainline-alpine
WORKDIR D:\code\project
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

./php/Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

And I also updated the docker-compose.yml to reflect the path of both Dockerfiles

```
version: "3"

services:
    web:
        build: ./nginx
        volumes:
            - D:\code\project:/usr/share/nginx/html
        ports:
            - "80:80"

    php:
        build: ./php
        volumes:
            - D:\code\project:/usr/share/nginx/html
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
```